# SimpleCV side by side view and sift features

Tags: sift, simplecv, keypoint

Since I'm a beginner to SimpleCV, can somebody please guide me with the following application: The thing is that I'm working on a stereo project. I have two images, from left and right eyes.

- First: I must display them side by side. (After using features and keypoints drawing it is able to show two images side by side but how can i do this manually?)
- Second: I will track any mouse click event on any of these images. Then extract the point of click event and mark its location on the other image after a sift detection. (Since left and right views have an intersection, clicked pixel is most likely to be on the other with a little offset/shift). I may use sift features or any other similar method offered in SimpleCV. But by default features use SURF algorithm for detection. How can I switch to sift algorithm and use it? should I create a features object somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show two images side by side you can use

`img1.sideBySide(img2)`

For more information about it, start the SimpleCV shell,

```
$ simplecv
SimpleCV:1> help(Image.sideBySide)
```

This will show you the complete docs of sideBySide function.

**KeyPoints**:

You can use any of the following algorithms for keyPoints.

- SURF
- STAR
- FAST
- MSER
- ORB
- SIFT

`img.findKeyPoints(flavour="SIFT")`

Again for more info, just use `help(Image.findKeyPoints)` in SimpleCV shell.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was useful. sideBySide is done. But how can I extract the custom keyPoint (where I clicked) on the other image using these algorithms?

Comment: You can get the clicked points using pygame. What you can do is use findKeyPointMatch() which will return you a FeatureSet of Key Points. you can match those with the clicked ones.

Comment: I had to use lowercase p with the American spelling of flavor: img.findKeypoints(flavor="SIFT")